path = 'pubspec.lock' (OS Error: Access is denied. , errno = 5)
how i get access from this pubsec.lock deny to run my project
because when ever i open vs code then pubsec.lock file is automaticllay opend there and when i go my lib folder and open main dart and run the app but file can not the open
i try to visit pubsec.lock file and nothing to show how to get access open
